Blazor RadzenDataGrid OnRowRender and OnCellRender Delegates Causing Problems
I am using OnRowRender and OnCellRender to get custom alternating row colors on my grids.  The problem is that I'd like to centralize the code for this in a base object and these methods have to match a delegate setup by each grid.  Here is my general setup.
   private void OnRowRender(RowRenderEventArgs<WaybillDumpCandidate> args)
   {
       evenRow = !evenRow;
   }

   private void OnCellRender(DataGridCellRenderEventArgs<WaybillDumpCandidate> args)
   {
       if (args.Column.Grid.AllowAlternatingRows)
       {
           if (evenRow)
           {
               args.Attributes.Add("style", $"background-color: aliceblue;");
           }
           else
           {
               args.Attributes.Add("style", $"background-color: lightskyblue;");
           }
       }
   }

What I would like to do, since I'm not using the arguments passed in, is setup methods with a generic argument, or no parameters at all.  Is this possible?
